# Returning the sum of items depending on which type it is

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one field that I need to sum lets say named items
However that field can be part of group a or b
In the end I need to have all of the items summed for group a and group b

when I say grouped I mean there is a LEFT OUTER JOIN to another table the previous table has a type for the items and the one being joined has a group assigned for this item type

Sorry guys Im a little new to sql I am going to try out what you have given me an get back to you

Ok I feel like we are getting close just not yet allain's I can get them to separate but the issue I need to have both groups to sum on the same row which is difficult because I also have several LEFT OUTER JOIN's involved

Tyler's looks like it might work too so I am trying to hash that out real fast

Alain's seems to be the way to go but I have to tweek it a little more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the complexity of what you're asking but... shouldn't this do?

```
SELECT groupname, SUM(value)
FROM items
WHERE groupname IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY groupname
```

And if you don't care which of a or b the item belongs to then this will do:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM items
WHERE groupname IN ('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
SELECT column,SUM( column ) FROM table GROUP BY column
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that (Tyler's answer) what the question meant, or is it simply this;

```
SELECT sum(item), groupingField FROM someTable GROUP BY groupingField
```

or even:

```
SELECT count(*), item FROM someTable GROUP BY item
```

which will produce results like this:

```
sum(item)    |     groupingField
-------------+-----------------------
 71          |          A
 82          |          B
```

Questioner, perhaps you could clarify which you meant or if I'm oversimplifying?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.[Group], COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON B.ItemType=A.ItemType
GROUP BY B.[Group]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this Image ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R9ou.png))

```
SELECT category_id,SUM(amount) AS count  FROM expense GROUP BY category_id;
```