# How to sum up a field depending on an other field value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a small stored procedure on SQL server 2008. I have little knowledge on SQL queries, but enough to achieve simple tasks. However I came up with a problem I can't solve myself. Before I start explaining my problem, please pardon me if I spell a SQL query-word wrong because I am not a native English speaker.

I have 4 fields(CSV representation):

```
ID, NAME, VALUES, ANSWER
25, Tom , 2400 , 0                
25, Tom , 600 , 0                
25, Tom , 500 , 1                
25, Tom , 300 , 1                
27, Jerry, 100, 0                
27, Jerry, 20, 1                
27, Jerry, 60, 1                
27, Jerry, 2000, 0
```

What I want to do is group by the selection by its `ID` and `NAME`, Sum up it's values in a field named `positive when ANSWER = 1` and `negative when ANSWER = 0`.

```
ID, NAME, SUM, NEGATIVE, POSITIVE
25, Tom, 3000, 800                   
27, Jerry, 2100, 80
```

I Guess my question has been asked several times, but I wasn't able to find anything about it, probably because I am using the wrong terms. Anyway if someone could help that would save me a lot of time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563/sql-returning-the-sum-of-items-depending-on-which-type-it-is

Comment: +1, just because this is actually a pretty well asked question. (Also thanks to the editor.)  It's got simple, illustrative input data and actually shows the desired result set.

Comment: I agree with Matt, this is a well illustrated question and the objective is clear as water. This helps a lot for non-native English speakers. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll do so with a CASE statement.

```
select Id
        , Name
        , SUM(case when answer = 1 then Values else 0 end) as Positive
        , SUM(case when answer = 0 then Values else 0 end) as Negative
    from MyTable
    group by Id
        , Name
```

Comment: I think you need to remove Values from the select and group by clauses

Comment: @houlgap: That's what I noticed after having reread the question for the third time to make sure I did understand the question. Thanks for letting me know though, that's nice! =)

Comment: @Ephismen: Does this answer your question properly? Did I understand correctly your need, or sis I miss something?

Comment: Your answer is perfect, I couldn't expect more than that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your SQL with columns such as this:

`sum(case when answer=0 then values else 0 end) negative`

Answer (score 1):

Ephismen,

The example you give has a hidden problem in it.  Will you always have at least one positive and one negative?  What do you want to happen if you only have one or the other and not both.  Joining the table to itself will not work when you have multiple rows for each id and name.

A UNION of two separate queries will be able to answer these questions, but not sure if it applies for SQL server 2008.

You may be able to achieve this by using the group by clause for SQL as follows:

```
select id
     , name
     , sum (neg_values)    as negative
     , sum (pos_values)    as positive
  from                                    -- temporary table
     ( select id
            , name
            , sum (values) as neg_values
            , 0            as pos_values  -- placeholder
         from mytable
        where answer  = 0                 -- negative
        group by id
               , name
        union all
       select id
            , name
            , 0            as neg_values  -- placeholder
            , sum (values) as pos_values
         from mytable
        where answer  = 1                 -- positive
        group by id
               , name
      )
  group by id
         , name
```

The temporary table (inner select with union) will return rows similar to this:

```
id  name neg_value pos_value
25  tom       3000         0
25  tom          0       800
27  jerry     2100         0
27  jerry        0        80
```

The final select will return your desired results (summing them together).

Comment: In my case there will always be both so I do not have to worry about it, but what you pointed out is true. I will save you answer in the case I face this problem one day, and I will +1 it since this might help others.